# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to string implicitly

Tags: python, int

```
title = link.string
amount = title.strip().lstrip("$")


try:
    print(type(float(amount)))
    check = "True"
    print(amount + 30) #This doesnt work
except ValueError:
    print(type(amount))
    check = "False"
```

I dont know what im doing wrong any help will be appreciated

Print(type(float(amount + 3)))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Your error does not match your code, regardless I imagine you want `float(amount) + 3` or `amount = float(title.strip().lstrip("$"))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `amount = float(title.strip().lstrip("$"))` worked, however i dont understand why. Thanks for the help by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable *amount* comes from a *lstrip* result, that means that the type of *amount* is *str*.
So, given this, the sentence

```
amount + 30
```

will return an exception.
You should parse amount before trying to add a number (type *int* in that case):

```
float(amount) + 30
```

The exception in Python 3 is:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

But in Python 2 is:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Your sentence:

```
print(amount + 30)
```

first resolves:

```
amount + 30
```

and then takes the result and try to print it. The error is before printing it, when adding. 
Python doesn't parse the text implicitly in that case.